# A exercise involving Poincaré- Bendixson's Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following exercise?

Show that if  $X=\left ( X_{1},X_{2} \right )$ is a class field $C^{1}$ in $\Delta \subset R^{2}$, $\Delta$ simply connected set, with

$\textrm{div} X=\frac{\partial X_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial X_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}\neq 0$ for all points of $\Delta$, then $X$ it does not have periodic orbits in $\Delta$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are actually referring to what is known as **Bendixon-Dulac Theorem**. Wikipedia supplies a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) (take $\varphi\left(x,y\right)\equiv 1$).